# Why do the Bad Girls wear these outfits?

Tags: angel-n-devil

Before going out on missions, the Bad Girls dress up in stylish uniforms, do their hair, put on makeup, and so forth. These outfits don't involve masks or anything, and are mostly just nice clothing. But nor are they uniforms for the purposes of identifying the group, which isn't really their goal anyway.

None of them really seem to think this will prevent people who know them from recognizing them, though (except for Yin Hsiang-Feng), as we see with the principal.

So why do they always wear these outfits?

Comment: It's called fashion, dahling. You wouldn't understand.

Comment: @Valorum - Possibly. But given the nature of the show, there's likely another explanation, if possibly a very funny one. For instance, at first  it seemed like the outfits actually were supposed to disguise them somehow.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the goal of the show is to show as much t&a as the censor will allow before the watershed.

Comment: @Valorum - That appears to be true as well. But then, one could say the same about another, much more popular show that's inundated the site with questions recently.

Comment: I've just got to the bit where they all change into black leather fetishwear. Totally demanded by the plot and not at all pandering.

Comment: @Valorum - You're actually watching it? But seriously, it's about ten times more tame than *Game of Thrones*.

Comment: I'm just flicking through episodes now. It appears to be borderline softcore pornography, albeit with lower production values and less overt nudity.

Comment: @Valorum - I'd call that an exaggeration. It might look like that at the start, what with the heavily blurred "pervert" "humor" in the first episode, but from what I can see after ten episodes it's almost entirely less risque from there, with literally zero sex scenes, and like, one kiss. If it's borderline softcore pornography, then Game of Thrones etc is hardcore pornography and something like Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D with (albeit tame) occasional sex scenes is also in that class.